# Lookup horizontal and vertical values in irregular table

Tags: excel

I am looking for a formula that returns the salary (100-2100) from the table below when fed the scale (1-5, first row) and step (1-13, vertical).

For example, scale 3 step 7 should return 1100.

Any help would be much appreciated!

EDIT: I have a messy working solution, so this is not me using SO as a "code writing service". The formula I'm looking for would just be a cleaner way of doing things. As far as I can tell, five things need to happen at the same time:

1. lookup 'scale' on the first row
2. return the column in which scale was found
3. lookup 'step' in the column from 2.
4. return the row in which 'step was found
5. lookup value of column A based on row from 4.

I just don't have the knowledge to implement this in a single formula, hence me asking. Thanks for your help.

```
        A             B    C    D    E    F
    +---------------+----+----+----+----+----+
 1  | salary/scale  | 1  | 2  | 3  | 4  | 5  |
    +---------------+----+----+----+----+----+
 2  | 100,00        |  0 |    |    |    |    |
 3  | 200,00        |  1 |  0 |    |    |    |
 4  | 300,00        |  2 |  1 |    |    |    |
 5  | 400,00        |  3 |  2 |  0 |    |    |
 6  | 500,00        |  4 |  3 |  1 |    |    |
 7  | 600,00        |  5 |  4 |  2 |    |    |
 8  | 700,00        |  6 |  5 |  3 |  0 |    |
 9  | 800,00        |  7 |  6 |  4 |  1 |    |
10  | 900,00        |  8 |  7 |  5 |  2 |  0 |
11  | 1000,00       |  9 |  8 |  6 |  3 |    |
12  | 1100,00       | 10 |  9 |  7 |  4 |  1 |
13  | 1200,00       |    | 10 |  8 |  5 |  2 |
14  | 1300,00       |    | 11 |  9 |  6 |  3 |
15  | 1400,00       |    | 12 | 10 |  7 |  4 |
16  | 1500,00       |    |    | 11 |  8 |  5 |
17  | 1600,00       |    |    | 12 |  9 |  6 |
18  | 1700,00       |    |    | 13 | 10 |  7 |
19  | 1800,00       |    |    |    | 11 |  8 |
20  | 1900,00       |    |    |    | 12 |  9 |
21  | 2000,00       |    |    |    |    | 10 |
22  | 2100,00       |    |    |    |    | 11 |
23  | 2200,00       |    |    |    |    | 12 |
    +---------------+----+----+----+----+----+
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question appears to be related to this question: [Reference a range using column number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18375012/reference-a-range-using-column-number)

The answer to my question is therefore (with scale=3 and step=7):

```
=OFFSET(A1;MATCH(7;INDEX(B2:F23;0;3);0);0)
```

Many thanks to Barry Houdini who provided the answer in the related question.

-

Breaking down the code:

lookup 'scale' (3) in the first row and return the column number in which scale was found:

```
=3 (per definition, the scale number equals the column number)
```

Define the range in which to search for 'step' (based on Barry Houdini's answer):

```
=INDEX(B2:F23;0;3)
```

lookup 'step' (7) in the range defined above and return the row number in which it was found:

```
=MATCH(7;INDEX(B2:F23;0;3);0)
```

lookup the salary in column A with the row number found above:

```
=OFFSET(A1;MATCH(7;INDEX(B2:F23;0;3);0);0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming J16=3, K16=7 (located somewhere not on the lookup table), you can use this:

```
=OFFSET(INDIRECT(IF(J16=B1,"B"&MATCH(K16,B2:B24),IF(J16=C1,"C"&MATCH(K16,C2:C24),"D"&MATCH(K16,D2:D24)))),1,-3)
```

Which will match on the first three columns and return the value in column A.

I will leave it to you to add the other two columns, as well as map it to your specific scale/step cells.

Furthermore, I'm sure this could be more efficient using some kind of hlookup, but I assume you can play with it and make it better yourself.